# What is the difference between [currency] and [money]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, Law SE has tags [currency](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency) and [money](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money). Neither tag has usage guidance. Are they synonyms?

Answer (score 3):

**All currency is/was money but not all money is currency.**

Currency is money which is authorised by law: UK Pounds, US Dollars, Thai Baht etc.

Money is anything that is used as a store of value and medium of exchange: All currency **plus** bitcoins, cigarettes in a prison, virtual money in an online game, gold, silver etc.

Now, there is also currency that is no longer money: Confederate States of America Dollars, Reichsmarks, coins minted by King John of England etc.

However, for our purposes, it's probably OK to consider them synonyms.